how to reverse the entries of an array
After tex-ing up many arrays, I realize to my horror that I need to reverse them.  In order words, instead of
\[
  \begin{array}{cccccccc}
     x & y & z & w
     \\
     1 & 2 & 3 & 4
  \end{array}
\]

I need
\[
  \begin{array}{cccccccc}
     w & z & y & x
     \\
     4 & 3 & 2 & 1
  \end{array}
\]

Is there a built-in/more humane way to do this short of retyping all the tables?  Many thanks!

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Maybe try something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317425/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392881/is-there-any-code-to-reverse-the-order-of-the-column-of-a-table

if your input is regular eg each table row is on one line, with the same number of & it should be easy to just re-order all the rows in one go in any editor. If your input is less systematic it may be a bit harder

How many is "many"?  It may not be appetizing, but sometimes getting your data into the format you need is worth the extra effort.

For the fun of it here is a starting point.  But you need to add \fix at start of any line to be permuted and also an inconvenience is that you must make sure last line has a \\ (adding it if absent does not change output,it does not add a new empty line anyhow).
I am proposing this because it is much easier in suitable text editor to add manually \fix, possibly with some aid from simple search/replace identifying lines with & in them, than to do use said editor to navigate to incriminated lines and manipulate them.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\def\fix #1\\{\fix@i #1&^^A&\\}
\def\fix@i#1&{\fix@ii{#1}}
\def\fix@ii#1#2&{\ifx^^A#2\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
                 {#1}{\fix@ii{#2&#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

original
\[
  \begin{array}{cccccccc}
    x & y & z & w
    \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4
  \end{array}
\]

fixed
\[
  \begin{array}{cccccccc}
\fix    x & y & z & w
    \\
\fix    1 & 2 & 3 & 4
    \\
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}

Use of package array in the above is not related to proposed solution.  It is only that many packages load array, so it is better to always have it, as it changes some things in output when vertical rules are involved.


edit
For people using lualatex where ^^A is a priori not an admissible token, here is variant which will work
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`$ 4 % Give $ an unusual catcode (anyhow even with its normal
             % catcode it is not very plausible in an array cell, but
             % let's be very cautious)
\gdef\fix #1\\{\fix@i #1&$&\\}
\gdef\fix@i#1&{\fix@ii{#1}}
\gdef\fix@ii#1#2&{\ifx$#2\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
                 {#1}{\fix@ii{#2&#1}}}
\endgroup
\makeatother

You can use the above also with pdflatex and I probably should have done something like that to start with.

perhaps I could have used $ for example as sentinel token rather than ^^A.  But syntax highlighting in my editor would have been inconvenient at the location of the \fix and auxiliaries definitions.

Thanks @user691586 --- this is brilliant!

@underflow Thanks, I will add an edit because my delimiter ^^A is not suitable for lualatex.

I could have still used ^^A with luatex by simply doing \catcode1=12 in a group and using \gdef as in the version with $...

If your input is regular you should be able to re-order in any text editor, I use the command line editor sed here. That is standard in linux but also a available on windows etc, but any editor with regular expression replace would work.
If file.tex has
\[
  \begin{array}{cccccccc}
     x & y & z & w
     \\
     1 & 2 & 3 & 4
  \end{array}
\]

The following command line
sed -e 's/^\([^&]*\)&\([^&]*\)&\([^&]*\)&\([^&]*\)$/\4\&\3\&\2\&\1/' file.tex

outputs
\[
  \begin{array}{cccccccc}
 w& z & y &     x 
     \\
 4& 3 & 2 &     1 
  \end{array}
\]

Note this re-orders the data but doesn't adjust the preamble (although in this case as that is cccccc no adjustment is needed)
When applying global regular expression replace to your document there are a few rules to follow:

back up the document before applying the edit
back up the document before applying the edit
back up the document before applying the edit


Thanks @carlisle.  Unfortunately the entries of my arrary are much more complicated than that.  But I will keep the sed comment in mind for future use.

@underflow it may be worth doing a query-replace on your input source removing ends of lines so that you do have one logical array row per line, then the above will work.  it doesn't matter how complicated the cells are so long as you have the same number of & per line
